# Let $X$ be a metric space and $A \subset X$. Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence in $A$. Show that every limit point of $(x_n)$ is in $\overline{A}$.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, solution-verification

> Let $X$ be a metric space and $A \subset X$. Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence in $A$. Show that every limit point of $(x_n)$ is in $\overline{A}$.

Note that $\overline{A}$ is closed. Assume that $(x_n)$ converges to some $x \in X\setminus \overline{A}$. Now $X\setminus \overline{A}$ is open so there exists $K >0$ such that $\forall n>K$ we have that $x_n \in X\setminus \overline{A}$ which is a contradiction so $x$ must be in $\overline{A}$? Is this a valid solution or is there some alternative way I could have done this?

Comment: Seems right. Alternatively, WLOG assume $x_n$ converges to $x$. For any open set $U$ containing $x$, there is some $N$ that makes $x_N \in U$  [definition of convergence], thus $U \cap A$ is nonempty, which means $x \in \overline A$ by the definition of closure.

Comment: How did you define $\overline{A}$ in the text?

Comment: Closure of $A$.

Comment: and the closure of $A$ is defined how?

Comment: $\overline{A} = \{x \in X \mid \text{ every neighbourhood of $x$ coincides with $A$ } \}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your definition $$\overline{A} = \{x \in X\mid \text{ every neighbourhood of } x\text{ intersects } A\}$$
there is a more direct proof: suppose $x_n \to x$ where all $x_n \in A$. Let $O$ be any neighbourhood of $x$. There exists $N \in \Bbb N$ so that for all $n \ge N$ we have $x_n \in O$. In particular $O_N \in A \cap O$ so that $O$ intersects $A$. As $O$ was arbitrary we know $x \in \overline{A}$.

Your proof also works once you know that $\overline{A}$ is closed so $U:=X\setminus \overline{A}$ is open, so that the assumption $x \notin \overline{A}$ implies $x \in U$ so $x_N$ in $U$ for some $N$ (as before from the convergence), which is a contradiction as $x_N \in A \subseteq \overline{A}$, so $x_N \notin U$. But this is less direct I find.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually straightforward to show that $\bar A=A\cup A'$, where $A'$, the so-called *derived set*, is the set of limit points of $A $.